# Select Union mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, where, distinct

Alguém poderia ajudar-me com este problema? A query abaixo lança o seguinte erro:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'u.idocorrencia' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
        (SELECT  o.*, u.nome AS requerente FROM ocorrencia o, utilizador u WHERE u.idutilizador = 2 AND perfil = 2)
        UNION ALL
    (SELECT  o1.*, u1.nome AS tecnico FROM utilizador u1, ocorrencia o1 WHERE u1.idutilizador != 2 AND u1.perfil = 1) 
    ) AS t WHERE u.idocorrencia = u1.idocorrencia and u.requerente <> u1.tecnico
```

As tabelas envolvidas na query são:

```
tabela utilizador (idutilizador, nome, perfil);

tabela ocorrencia (idocorrencia, ocorrencia, descricao);

tabela utilizador_ocorrencia (ocorrencia_id, utilizador_id);
```

Comment: Qual erro? O que você espera retornar com esta query? Clique em [edit] e adicione esses detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.idocorrencia' in 'where clause'

Comment: espero que retome o idocorrencia | assunto | descricao | requerente | tecnico

Comment: Nota: requerente e tecnico fazem parte da tabela utilizador

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando uma sub-consulta. A partir do "as t", você não pode mais fazer referência aos alias "u" e "u1" da sub-consulta, ou seja, das tabelas internas. 
Talvez fosse melhor se você colocasse a estrutura das tabelas. Mas veja se a consulta abaixo pode lhe ajudar:

```
  SELECT distinct o.*, u.nome as requerente, u1.nome as tecnico 
  FROM ocorrencia o
  left join utilizador u  on (o.idocorrencia = u.idocorrencia)
  left join utilizador u1 on (o.idocorrencia = u1.idocorrencia)
  where ((u.idutilizador = 2 AND perfil = 2)
    or (u.idutilizador != 2 AND perfil = 1))
    AND u.nome <> u1.nome
```

ou esta :

```
select o.*, u.nome as requerente, u1.nome as tecnico
from ocorrencia o 
  inner join utilizador_ocorrencia uo on (o.idocorrencia = ocorrencia_id)
  left join utilizar u on (u.idutilizador = uo.utilizador_id and u.perfil = 2)
  left join utilizar u1 on (u1.idutilizador = uo.utilizador_id and u1.perfil = 1)
where u.idutilizador <> u1.idutilizador
```

Comment: Boas Eduardo, não funcionou

Comment: Envia a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na consulta da resposta. Faz outro teste aí. Se não funcionar, envie a estrutura das tabelas para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Eduardo, você postou duas respostas aparentemente identicas. Sugiro que una-as apenas nesta e delete a outra.

Comment: Feito @DiegoF. As respostas tinham algumas diferenças, mas você está certo em colocar tudo junto. Obrigado!